# When click on notification from OneSignal, open the URL in the same tab

Tags: onesignal

I am using [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) to send notifications on an android device where I have installed the basic android app from the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup).

Every notification contains a link, so when the user clicks on it a browser opens to the specified URL. The problem is that every time the user clicks on a notification a new tab is opened.

Is there a way to set the onesignal notification to open the URL in the same tab every time?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-options#click-behavior):

> If users do not have your site open on any browser tabs, and click on
> a notification that takes them to your site, the browser will open a
> new tab and navigate to the notification's URL.
>
> If users have your site open on one or more browser tabs, and click on
> a notification that takes them to your site, there are several
> possible ways the browser can behave that you can configure:
>
> **Exact Navigate** (default) - If the notification's exact URL (e.g.
> example.com/product) matches a tab that the browser already has open,
> the browser will navigate to the notification's URL in that tab.
>
> **Origin Navigate** - If the notification's origin (e.g. example.com)
> matches a tab that the browser already has open, the browser will
> navigate to the notification's URL in that tab.
>
> **Exact Focus** - If the
> notification's exact URL (e.g. example.com/product) matches a tab that
> the browser already has open, the browser will focus on that tab, but
> not refresh the page.
>
> **Origin Focus** - If the notification's origin
> (e.g. example.com) matches a tab that the browser already has open,
> the browser will focus on that tab, but not refresh the page.

I've also tried and it works.

Also, if you whish to reload some data you could register an event handler for the [click on the notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-sdk#notification-clicked) and perform the reload in this function.

```
function clickEventListener(event) {
  console.log(`click event: ${event}`);
}

OneSignal.Notifications.addEventListener("click", clickEventListener);
```

Comment: Hey @xfox,
I'm looking how we can indeed configure the click behaviour, I found the documentation you're mentioning, but impossible to find which or where to put a parameter to indeed apply this configuration... Any idea?

Comment: Finally found my answer. See here for reference: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/1160